# How can I use the convert program of ImageMagick and also keep the quality?

Tags: 22.04, convert, quality

I have a lot of .ps images and I need them in .png, so I found that the `convert` program could help me, however, every time I did the conversion like this: `convert foo.ps foo.png` the quality of the resulting image was very low. After reading the manual, I tried: `convert foo.ps -quality 100 foo.png`, but I didn't get different results, neither raising the 100 to 200 or more.

Comment: When I save a PNG image with another program (Gimp), which has a graphical interface, I am offered a "compression" factor for PNGs in the range of 1-9. I think it's JPGs that have a quality range like 1-100. I don't know how relevant this is.

Answer (score 1):

After several searches on other websites (outside of Ask Ubuntu) I found the solution regarding the quality. The code would be like this: `convert -density 300 foo.ps -quality 100 foo.png`.

Comment: That value of `300` looks very much like a DPI value (as in Dot Per Inch)? (`density` could refer to pixel density, which indeed makes sense to express in DPI units). If yes, then it would be impacting the "resolution" of the image... Also, if this indeed is the case, a `density` value of e.g. `500`, or more, could result in huge pixel counts, and thus, huge file sizes.